# Two non isometric Hilbert space which are isomorphic as two Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I wonder  if  there is an obvious  example of two  non isometric  Hilbert  spaces  $H, K$  which  are isomorphic  Banach spaces?

Comment: I must be missing something here, otherwise the answer seems like an obvious "no" due to the polarization formula $$\langle x,y\rangle = \frac{1}{4}(\|x+y\|^2 - \|x-y\|^2)$$(Valid in the real case, but there's an analogue in the complex case).

Comment: @IvoTerek: but isomorphism of Banach spaces is not necessarily isometric.

Comment: @Martin Of course. I read it too fast and thought that OP was asking for the Banach spaces to be isometrically isomorphic too. Duh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, if two Hilbert spaces are isomorphic as Banach spaces (even in the category of Banach spaces and bounded linear maps) then they're isomorphic as Hilbert spaces (in the sense that they are isometric). A Hilbert space is determined up to isometry by its Hilbert space dimension, which is the size of a Hilbert orthonormal basis; this is also the size of the smallest collection of vectors whose span is dense (by Gram-Schmidt), which means it's also an isomorphism invariant of Banach spaces (again, even in the category of Banach spaces and bounded linear maps).

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question and your interesting answer!